# Table width on Outlook in Windows not taking up width indicated

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am making an email campaign and below are 2 buttons.  I am using Litmus to test them and they look fine on every platform except for Outlook in Windows.  The width just takes the width of the text inside and doesn't take the width given, which is 336px.  Am I doing something wrong?

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir-Medium, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Avenir-Medium, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
      <a href="Foo" class="button button-green" target="_blank" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff; border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; width: 336px; height: 51px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: Avenir-Medium, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: 49px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: center; color: #000000;">Fooo</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 336px; font-family: Avenir-Medium, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
  <tr style="width:336px">
    <td style="width: 336px; font-family: Avenir-Medium, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
      <a href="foo" class="button button-green" target="_blank" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #ffffff; background-color: #f04b93; border-top: 10px solid #f04b93; border-right: 18px solid #f04b93; border-bottom: 10px solid #f04b93; border-left: 18px solid #f04b93; width: 336px; height: 51px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: Avenir-Medium, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: 31px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">Foo</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I can help here:

1. Don't bother defining any properties on table rows. Your use of width on the second button on the table row, isn't valid HTML. Stick to defining widths on tables and table cells.
   Although, in your case, there is no need to define a width on the table cells and you only have one table cell inside each table. Your table cells will naturally inherit the width from the parent table.
2. Display block will not do anything in Outlook. Remove those.
3. flexbox and border box won't work in Outlook and most email clients, so no need to include the box-sizing property.
4. Widths on  tags are redundant in Outlook too. Remove those.
5. Buttons in Outlook are tricky for those less experienced with email development. You will actually need some Outlook specific code to pad out your buttons as you are hoping.
   Try this email button generator from Campaign Monitor - https://buttons.cm/

Give the button generator a go and see how that works for you :)